# Phone unable to recover after app crashes

Tags: applications, root-access, crashes

I am using a rooted S4 device for app development purpose. I have joined a new team and working on their Android app. I see a weird issue on my phone, that if my app crashes, after the ANR, the screen goes blank, back/menu/home buttons dont work at all. At best I can suspend/screen lock my phone - but even after unlock, the state of the phone doesn't change (sometimes it returns to a normal state after 1-2 minutes).

What worries me most i that this does not happen to the other members of the development team; nor does this happen if I crash any other app on my phone.

I am concerned more about is this a problem with my phone, my app, or rooting ? Logs are not showing anything unusual.